# Changed my user directory name in /Users without being root and permissions are messed up

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I tried changing the name of the directory back, but when logging back into the old user the files weren't picked up.

So now I have all my files and programs on a new user but I don't have permission for things like /usr/local/etc.

Is there a way to fix this from the settings or do I have to go back and give myself permission manually?

If I have to do it manually, which directories should I mod?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE: This technique works in Linux, only assuming the same is true for OSX.*

**To fix permissions in your home directory**

Open a terminal:

```
# ls -ld /Users/christophe
# chown -R christophe:christophe /Users/christophe
# ls -ld /Users/christophe
```

You may also need to `chmod 700 /Users/christophe`

EDIT: [This might be the safer route](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10669).

**To fix permissions outside your home directory**

[Use Disk Utility's Repair Disk permissions feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452)